# Rails - delete route goes to destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, routes, action

I have a Passenger and Driver model with their corresponding controllers (I can't setup a sessions controller to encapsulate both of their logins and logout). I am trying to delete the session when logging out but the link for logging out goes to the destroy action because it has a delete method, but I want it to go the logout action in the passengers controller since the destroy action is for destroying the passenger, not its session.

Heres the rails error:

```
Missing template passengers/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=
>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. 
Searched in: * "/Users/hamed/Coding/BikeMe/app/views"
```

Here are my passengers routes (I have a duplicate of the same code for drivers as well):

```
resources :passengers do
  get '/dashboard' => 'passengers#dashboard'
end

post '/passengers/login'   => 'passengers#login'
delete '/passengers/logout'  => 'passengers#logout'
```

Heres the link:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-method="delete" href="/passengers/logout">Logout as 
passenger</a>
```

Heres the actions in the passengers_controller:

```
def login
  @passenger = Passenger.find_by_email(params[:passenger][:email])
  if @passenger && @passenger.authenticate(params[:passenger][:password])
    session[:passenger_id] = @passenger.id
    render :dashboard
  else
    redirect_to '/passengers/new', :notice => "Invalid login. Try again"
  end
end

def logout
  session[:passenger_id].clear
  redirect_to '/passengers/login'
end

def destroy
end
```

Comment: Try moving the `delete '/passengers/logout'  => 'passengers#logout'` line above the `resources :passengers` line. [The priority of the routes is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08754f12e65a9ec79633a605e986d0f1ffa4b251/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/routes.rb#L2) . The delete route that comes with resources definition might be conflicting with the new delete route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you're describing does make it sound like you'd be better off with two separate controllers. Even the way you describe it, you have to use two different nouns ("delete the session" versus "destroy the passenger"); consider whether it's possible to move the session-related actions out of this controller. I think it would be saner.

Other than that, I don't see any immediate problems in your code. It's worth asking, have you restarted all relevant services? I often make a small change, freak out when I don't see it reflected in the browser, then realize that I had to `touch tmp/restart` or something (depending on your web server).

What URL are you loading in order to get the error message you pasted at top? And can you paste in the log or console output for that URL request? (the stuff that appears in the console when you run `rails s`)

Comment: this is what the server says: `Started DELETE "/passengers/logout" for ::1 at 2015-04-30 14:51:05 -0700
Processing by PassengersController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"jPZtNUvxS1zy5rdpAcgfLLT47IjPsDi117wqq08R4HN5P74hlEGGo0goxnaVh1WcwtUb8Y0wYCHftra7KaY8mQ==", "id"=>"logout"} Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms`  So apparently it was going to passengers/:id and assuming that logout is the id.

Comment: Ahhhh those damn route IDs. :-) I think this is an example of what folks mean when they say "Rails works great when you hold to its conventions, but when you stray from them you make more work for yourself" -- by trying to mash the session stuff into the same controller I think you've made more work for yourself (and anyone else working on this app in the future). But at any rate, this should be solvable by reordering your route definitions such that `/passengers/logout` is evaluated BEFORE the standard RESTful routes are evaluated.

Comment: Did reordering the routes fix the problem? Please consider marking the answer as Accepted if so. Thanks!